# How to merge 2 data sets using 2 common columns in each in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge two data frames based on 2 columns in each. I want to merge the Territory column and IDMate column from Data Frame 2 to Data Frame 1 based on matching ID and Year columns.

Data Frame 1:

```
        ID Year
     1  1 1998
     2  2 2001
     3  3 2005
     4  4 2008
```

Data Frame 2:

```
       ID Year Territory  IDMate
    1  1 1998         A    22
    2  1 1999         B    24
    3  1 2000         C    25
    4  2 2001         D    26
    5  2 2002         E    27
    6  3 2005         F    28
    7  4 2008         G    29
```

Goal is to get this:

```
       ID Year Territory  IDMate
    1  1 1998         A    22
    2  2 2001         D    26
    3  3 2005         F    28
    4  4 2008         G    29
```

Comment: Simply `merge` should work`merge( dataframe1, dataframe2)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `left_join` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "Year"))

#  ID Year Territory IDMate
#   1 1998         A     22
#   2 2001         D     26
#   3 2005         F     28
#   4 2008         G     29
```

Answer (score -1):

common <- intersect(data.frame1$col, data.frame2$col)
data.frame2[common,]

Hopefully, this will get you what you want

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this code yet because I used the one George Wood recommended and it seemed to have worked. Thanks for helping! I really appreciate it!